# What density should I keep when i'm designing at 3x for an android mobile app in photoshop?

Tags: mobile, mobile-application, app

I've designed a mobile app design for couple of project, but still i couldn't understand the DPI concept.

I using photoshop for designing. Im doing design with the dimension of 1080*1920 - which is (3x - I guess i'm right) and with the density of 72. Is this right way of initializing a canvas size and density?

Could anybody guide me?

Answer (score 0):

Question was ask multiple times before. Just search for (android) app resolution and you get results that answer your question such as:

[Screen size to start designing for Android](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/55768/screen-size-to-start-designing-in-android)

[What is the generally accepted resolution for mobile design?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/36337/what-is-the-generally-accepted-resolution-for-mobile-design)

[What deliverables do I need to request from a visual designer for my Android app?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/23261/what-deliverables-do-i-need-to-request-from-a-visual-designer-for-my-android-app)

...and much more.

In short form said you should focus on adaptive layouts which can fit on multiple devices instead of pixels. This is because of the wide range of available android phone sizes.

Comment: If a question has been asked before then please flag it as a duplicate. Don't just answer it.

Comment: Alright Jon I will do it next time. Thanks for the Feedback.